# failed (22: Invalid argument) while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am following a tuturial to get a new Django website online but I keep getting a 502 Bad Gateway error.

When checking the error log I see this message keep coming back:

When I enter gezelligehotelletjes.com:8000

```
2015/12/20 13:47:02 [crit] 2194#0: *3 connect() to 0.0.31.65:80 failed (22: Invalid argument) while connecting to upstream, client: 95.96.206.181, server: 45.79.160.100, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsg$ "uwsgi://0.0.31.65:80", host: "www.gezelligehotelletjes.com:8000"
```

And when I enter the IP address: 45.79.160.100

```
2015/12/20 13:48:32 [crit] 2194#0: *6 connect() to 0.0.31.65:80 failed (22: Invalid argument) while connecting to upstream, client: 95.96.206.181, server: 45.79.160.100, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsg$ "uwsgi://0.0.31.65:80", host: "45.79.160.100:8000"
```

This is the project tree I am currently working with:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── media
│   │   └── media.png
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── uwsgi_params
│   └── wsgi.py
├── mysite_nginx.conf
├── mysite.sock
├── static
│   └── admin
│       ├── css
│       │   ├── base.css
│       ├── fonts
│       │   ├── README.txt
│       ├── img
│       │   ├── calendar-icons.svg
│       └── js
│           ├── actions.js
└── test.py
```

Currently I am not using the socket, but for now I have created an empty file "mysite.sock" in the root directory.

These are the contents of mysite_nginx.conf:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    # server localhost:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name gezelligehotelletjes.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/johan/gezelligehotelletjes/gezelligehotelletjes/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/johan/gezelligehotelletjes/gezelligehotelletjes/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/johan/gezelligehotelletjes/gezelligehotelletjes/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

And the contents of uwsgi_params:

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

I read I only had to copy and paste this into this file, but maybe this needs to be changed as well.

When I visit gezelligehotelletjes.com or 45.79.160.100 I get to see the "Welcome to NGinx" page.

The server is running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am using a virtualenv.

I have been looking around on the web for proper solutions but I have not been able to figure it out yet after working on it for the last couple of days. 
I really hope someone can help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `upstream` container. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server) for details. Try either of these (or the server's real IP address):

```
upstream django { server localhost:8001; }
upstream django { server 127.0.0.1:8001; }
```

Generally it isn't necessary to put the IP address into the `server_name` directive. If you do, it should **not** have a leading `.`. If this is the only server listening on port 8000, it is the implicit default server, and therefore responds to any server name anyway. You can omit the server_name altogether if you don't wish to specify the FQDN. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more about server names.

Comment: I have tried what you said, but I still get a 502 error. I have updated the question so that it matches the current situation. I have been able to reach gezelligehotelletjes.com:8000/media/media.png, but when I run uwsgi --socket gezelligehotelletjes.sock --uwsgi-file test.py I get the 502 error.

Comment: So you have switched to a unix socket. Are you sure that the pathnames in the upstream block and the service command line match? What does the error log say now?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.The tutorial said we had to change to sockets because there is less  overhead. the error I get right now is `2015/12/22 18:24:21 [crit] 23345#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/johan/gezelligehotelletjes/gezelligehotelletjes/gezelligehotelletjes.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 95.96.206.181, server: gezelligehotelletjes.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/johan/gezelligehotelletjes/gezelligehotelletjes/gezelligehotelletjes.sock:", host: "gezelligehotelletjes.com:8000`

Comment: @JohanVergeer Check permissions of the directory containing the socket.

Comment: The project is in `/home/johan/gezelligehotelletjes` This has all the proper permissions settings. inside the the folder `home/johan/gezelligehotelletjes/gezelligehotelletjes` I placed gezelligehotelletjes.sock which is empty at the moment.

Comment: @JohanVergeer What are the proper permissions? What is the owner? And which user does `nginx` run under?

Comment: home=755 johan=755 gezelligehotelletjes=775 gezelligehotelletjes=775 nginx is run under user "johan"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98742/discussion-between-richard-smith-and-johan-vergeer).